# Finding which parts of a string does not match the regex

Tags: python, regex

I have written a program which checks email addresses entered by a user against a regex. When a user enters an incorrect email that does not match the regex, a print statement is executed telling the user that the email is incorrect. What i want to do is be able to tell them why the email is incorrect, in other words identify the parts of the regex that the email entered by the user does not match. I am unsure of how to do this.

```
import re
student = []
while True:
    email = input("Please enter the email, for eg test@hotmail.com")
    if not re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]{5,25}@{1}[A-Za-z]{5,15}[.]{1}[A-Za-z {3,10}$", email):
        print("Sorry incorrect format, please re-enter email")
    else:
        student.append(email)
        print(student)
        break
```

Comment: What kind of messages you want to show by the way?

Comment: Regex either matches or it doesn't... there is no grey area.  You would need to parse the email address in code and report on specific problems.  In reality, it probably wont help the user that much.

Comment: Your regex to test for valid email addresses does not allow for the full range of possibilities like dot separated names, addition symbols, multiple segmented domain names. For example: `Ro.Yo.Me+stackoverflow@ix.netcom.com` is completely valid per the standard, but would fail your test. Also you have an error in your expression, the last character class is missing the closing bracket.

Comment: @BaileyS you're right a regex will either match or not match, however with optional lookaheads it's possible to construct an expression that will test and report on any errors.

Comment: Yes exactly what i want it to do is tell me where the errors are?.....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an existing library for this. Perhaps you can use this instead of recreating the wheel:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email

or this:

https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator

Answer (score 0):

## Foreward

There are a lot of rules that describe a valid email address. My proposed solution here is only test the rules you described in your original question `^[A-Za-z0-9]{5,25}@{1}[A-Za-z]{5,15}[.]{1}[A-Za-z {3,10}$`

I recommend making the following changes to your base expression:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{5,25}@{1}[A-Za-z]{5,15}[.]{1}[A-Za-z {3,10}$
  2                1   2               1   2     3
```

1. remove the `{1}` quantifier, as these are not necessary
2. remove the `A-Z` from the character classes, and use the case insensitive flag
3. insert a closing `]` on the last character class

The resulting expression looks like:

```regex
^[a-z0-9]{5,25}@[A-Za-z]{5,15}[.][a-z]{3,10}$
```

## Description

`^(?=(?:.*?@.*?(?P<TooManyAtSigns>@))?)(?=(?P<NoAtSign>[^@\n]*$)?)(?=(?:[a-z0-9]*?(?P<BadCharacterInUsername>[^a-z0-9@\n]))?)(?=(?:.*?@[a-z.]*?(?P<BadCharacterInDomain>[^a-z.\n]))?)(?=(?:(?:(?P<UsernameTooShort>[a-z0-9.]{0,4})|(?P<UsernameTooLong>[a-z0-9.]{26,}))@)?)(?=(?:.*?@(?:(?P<DomainNameTooShort>[A-Za-z]{0,4})|(?P<DomainNameTooLong>[a-z]{16,}))[.])?)(?=(?:.*?@(?P<DomainNameMissingDot>[^.\n]*)$)?)(?=(?:.*?@.*?[.](?:(?P<TopLevelDomainNameTooShort>[a-z]{0,2})|(?P<TopLevelDomainNameTooLong>[a-z]{11,}) )$)?)(?=(?:.*?(?P<FoundASpace>\ ))?)(?P<email>.*)$`

[image]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- Users hate playing an iterative game where they correct one thing at a time, so this expression tests everything upfront and will tell you everything that is wrong.
- Runs various tests, if these tests are found then the associated named capture group is populated. If the capture group is not populated, then the test passed

  - Too Many `@` characters
  - No `.` in the domain name section
  - find invalid characters. This test will only show the first invalid character found before the `@` and the first invalid character after the `@`
  - Username is too short or too long
  - Domain name is too short or long. e.g.: `@gm.com` or `@TheForceIsWithYouAllTheTime.com` Side note `gm.com` is a valid domain name for General Motors.
  - Top Level Domain Name is too short or too long. e.g.: `@gmail.au` or `@gmail.WhyIsThisNameSoLong` Side note `.au` is a valid top level name.
- Looks for spaces

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/cQ0jR6/2

**Sample text**

```
RoYoMi@gmail.com
RoY@gmail.com
RoYoMiInternationalManOfMystery@gmail.com
Ro!YoMi@@gmail.com
RoYoMi@gm.com
RoYoMiGmail.com
RoYoMi@gmco!m
RoYoMi@ThisIsNotTheDroidYouWereLookingFor.com
RoYoMi@gmail.co
RoYoMi@gmail.InterGalatic
RoY@@Gma.InterGalatic
RoYoMi@MoreDroidsYouAreNotLookingFor.com
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
email   [0-16]  `RoYoMi@gmail.com`

MATCH 2
UsernameTooShort    [17-20] `RoY`
email   [17-30] `RoY@gmail.com`

MATCH 3
UsernameTooLong [31-62] `RoYoMiInternationalManOfMystery`
email   [31-72] `RoYoMiInternationalManOfMystery@gmail.com`

MATCH 4
TooManyAtSigns  [81-82] `@`
BadCharacterInUsername  [75-76] `!`
BadCharacterInDomain    [81-82] `@`
email   [73-91] `Ro!YoMi@@gmail.com`

MATCH 5
DomainNameTooShort  [99-101]    `gm`
email   [92-105]    `RoYoMi@gm.com`

MATCH 6
NoAtSign    [106-121]   `RoYoMiGmail.com`
BadCharacterInUsername  [117-118]   `.`
email   [106-121]   `RoYoMiGmail.com`

MATCH 7
BadCharacterInDomain    [133-134]   `!`
DomainNameMissingDot    [129-135]   `gmco!m`
email   [122-135]   `RoYoMi@gmco!m`

MATCH 8
DomainNameTooLong   [143-177]   `ThisIsNotTheDroidYouWereLookingFor`
email   [136-181]   `RoYoMi@ThisIsNotTheDroidYouWereLookingFor.com`

MATCH 9
TopLevelDomainNameTooShort  [195-197]   `co`
email   [182-197]   `RoYoMi@gmail.co`

MATCH 10
TopLevelDomainNameTooLong   [211-223]   `InterGalatic`
email   [198-223]   `RoYoMi@gmail.InterGalatic`

MATCH 11
TooManyAtSigns  [228-229]   `@`
BadCharacterInDomain    [228-229]   `@`
UsernameTooShort    [224-227]   `RoY`
DomainNameTooShort  [229-232]   `Gma`
TopLevelDomainNameTooLong   [233-245]   `InterGalatic`
email   [224-245]   `RoY@@Gma.InterGalatic`

MATCH 12
DomainNameTooLong   [253-282]   `MoreDroidsYouAreNotLookingFor`
email   [246-286]   `RoYoMi@MoreDroidsYouAreNotLookingFor.com`
```